# Oracle stored procedure with OUT parameters calling from Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I called a stored procedure with OUT parameter through Hibernate and got the following error:

```
17:30:52,646 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_ACTIVITY_RECORDS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_ACTIVITY_RECORDS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

My Stored Procedure:

```
  create or replace 
    PACKAGE BODY  "TEST_NESTEDTAB_PKG" AS

      PROCEDURE GET_ACTIVITY_RECORDS( TEMP_RESULT OUT ACT_LOG_TYPE, USERNAME IN ACTIVITY_LOG.USER_NAME%TYPE) AS
      BEGIN
        SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO TEMP_RESULT
        FROM ACTIVITY_LOG
        WHERE USER_NAME  = USERNAME;
      END GET_ACTIVITY_RECORDS;

    END TEST_NESTEDTAB_PKG;
```

Hibernate mapping:

```
 <sql-query name="getactivityLog" callable="true">
    <return class="com.test.ps.domain.SPActiveLog">
        <return-property name="activityId" column="ACTIVITY_ID" />
        <return-property name="username" column="USER_NAME" />
        <return-property name="activityDate" column="ACTIVITY_DATE" />
        <return-property name="activity" column="ACTIVITY" />
        <return-property name="userId" column="USERID" />
        <return-property name="action" column="ACTION" />
        <return-property name="userRole" column="USER_ROLE" />
        <return-property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION" />
        <return-property name="category" column="CATEGORY" />
        <return-property name="result" column="RESULT" />
    </return>
    { call TEST_NESTEDTAB_PKG.GET_ACTIVITY_RECORDS(?,:USERNAME) }
</sql-query>
```

I called the stored procedure as follows:

```
    Query qry = getSession().getNamedQuery("getactivityLog");       
    qry.setParameter("USERNAME", "FACTORY TOPTAR TOTAIN");
    Object result = qry.list();
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{ ? = call TEST_NESTEDTAB_PKG.GET_ACTIVITY_RECORDS(:USERNAME) }
```

Documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/querysql-namedqueries.html

> **16.2.2. Using stored procedures for querying**
>
> Hibernate 3 introduces support for queries via stored procedures and
>   functions. **Most of the following documentation is equivalent for both**.
>   The stored procedure/function must return a resultset as the first
>   out-parameter to be able to work with Hibernate. An example of such a
>   stored function in Oracle 9 and higher is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectAllEmployments
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
    st_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN st_cursor FOR
 SELECT EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYER,
 STARTDATE, ENDDATE,
 REGIONCODE, EID, VALUE, CURRENCY
 FROM EMPLOYMENT;
      RETURN  st_cursor;
 END;
```

> To use this query in Hibernate you need to map it via a named query.

```
<sql-query name="selectAllEmployees_SP" callable="true">
    <return alias="emp" class="Employment">
        <return-property name="employee" column="EMPLOYEE"/>
        <return-property name="employer" column="EMPLOYER"/>
        <return-property name="startDate" column="STARTDATE"/>
        <return-property name="endDate" column="ENDDATE"/>
        <return-property name="regionCode" column="REGIONCODE"/>
        <return-property name="id" column="EID"/>
        <return-property name="salary">
            <return-column name="VALUE"/>
            <return-column name="CURRENCY"/>
        </return-property>
    </return>
    { ? = call selectAllEmployments() }
</sql-query>
```

> Notice stored procedures currently only return scalars and entities.
>    and  are not supported.